# How to create horizontal elements in responsive way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hi I am trying to create an effect to archive effect like the following

Desktop

```
//lines up items vertically
 ----------------------------
|   --------------
|  |     item1    |
|  |              |
|   --------------
|   --------------
|  |     item2    |
|  |              |
|   --------------
|   --------------
|  |     item3    |
|  |              |
|   --------------
```

in phone,

```
 ----------------------------
|   --------------   -----------------
|  |     item1    | |     item2       |  
|  |              | |                 |  //line up horizontally for all items
|   --------------   -----------------
|
 ----------------------------
```

I am using Angular and here is my codes.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="item-container col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="item in items">
              <div>{{item.name}}</div>
              //other html to show items infos...
         </li>
      </ul>
   <div>
</div>
```

In phone, I can only have limited items in one row (can only hold 3 items) and it will push 4th item to the next row because the `item-container` doesn't have enough width. I need all of my items (more than 10) are displayed horizontally. Is there anyways to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: u want all items to be visible on the screen at once, or when user swipes remaining to be shown ? Just want them to be placed horizontally ? You can use width in % eg- width : 10% if you have 10 items provided parent container is 100% wide

Comment: I want use to see partial of items and they can swipe right to see the rest.

Comment: Go for horizontal carousel. http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/zx8re147/

if you want to remove white-space between inline block add font-size:0 to parent

```css
.container {
 }
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
  .block {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

with whitespace removed

```
@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
    .container {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        font-size:0;
    }
    .block {
        display:inline-block;
        font-size:15px;
    }
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/zx8re147/1/

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question. Is this can be created by bootstrap without media query in css?

Comment: you will need to add styles in the media query or else the styles will not get applied

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need 2 styles 1 for the desktop and the other for phone so through media query use this style for your phone.

on elements inside container use

```
display: inline-block;
```

and on container use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```